# How to prevent or revert Chrome from randomly replacing the sites that show up in my new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, bookmarks

Chrome shows the most visited sites on my new tab page which is great. But sometimes it replaces one of these with a page that's still on that site but not the main page.

So if I am visiting superuser all the time, superuser.com will be there. But sometimes it replaces it with a page that navigates to one of the questions I looked up. So clicking it doesn't bring the main page.

Did I do something to trigger this? How can I revert this back to the main page?

Comment: that is quite amazing...because, chrome does show random screenshots for me too but the link is always correct..

in the mean time, have a look at these: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/speed%20dial?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: I agree that this is a strange quirk of Chrome’s. I rarely go to Google’s homepage since when I want to Google something, I just use the `g` code in the Omnibar; so I don’t need it in the MVP list. However, once in a while, Google will show up in the MVP list and what’s more strange is that it will be a link to a seemingly random search (usually a recent search) which of course is anything *but* frequently visited. On the other hand, whenever I go to Hotmail (which is in the MVP list), it always redirects to another URL, yet that URL never shows up in the list. The topsite algo is just broken.

Comment: Also, the thumbnails seem to have a lot of trouble being accurate as well. In fact, it recently took over a week for two of the MVP sites to even *have* thumbnails instead of being stuck with a broken image (in fact SuperUser itself had a broken image for a day or two). Unfortunately the New Tab Page simply has numerous issues. You can see some of them [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=new+tab+page).

Answer (score -1):

Pinning the 9 thumbnails would keep the most visited site to be constant even if you visit some part the particular domain. Elaborated explanation can be found [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95451)

Comment: Thanks, I searched for pinning in your link, but it only talks about opening the link as pinned tab. Is there an actual way to pin the pages in the new tab window?

Comment: [Link](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/google-chrome-pin-favorites-tab/) which helps you in add and customize the pinned pages

Comment: That seems like it's only in the older version, comments verify it too.